# How to perform calculation in map function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array of number, I want to calculate the square of numbers and display them in list.
Right now I am calculating squares separately and rendering them separately using map function as follows

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i] * arr[i];
}

render() {
  return html`<ul>
    ${arr.map(item => html`<li>${item}</li>`)}
  </ul>`;
}
```

Is there a way such that the operations are performed with map function. I am new to using map function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862347/function-that-squares-the-values-in-an-array could also help

Answer (score 2):

```
let arr=[1,2,3,4,5];

render(){
return html`<ul>
${arr.map(item => html`<li>${item * item}</li>`)}
</ul>`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the `square` operation inside the `arr.map` in `render function.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
render() {
  return html `<ul>
    ${arr.map(item => html`<li>${item * item}</li>`)}
  </ul>`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.pow()` to do calculation

```
let arr=[1,2,3,4,5];

render(){
return html`<ul>
${arr.map(item => html`<li>${Math.pow(item, 2)}</li>`)}
</ul>`
}
```